# why strcat_s causing problems

Tags: c++, strcat

I'm facing problem that I get random chars output instead of getting first and mid and last name combined which is the purpose of the program and when I run the debugger it says that the problem in strcat_s but I don't know what's the problem with it

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
class name {
private:
    char first[20], mid[20], last[20];
public:

    name();
    name(const char*, const char*, const char*);
    ~name();
    char* show();
};
name::name()
{
    first[0] = mid[0] = last[0] = '\0';
}
name::name(const char* f, const char* m, const char* l)
{
    size_t lenF = strlen(f), lenM = strlen(m), lenL = strlen(l);
    if (strlen(f) > 20) lenF = 20;
    else if (strlen(m) > 20) lenM = 20;
    else if (strlen(l) > 20) lenL = 20;
    strncpy_s(first, f, lenF);
    strncpy_s(mid, m, lenM);
    strncpy_s(last, l, lenL);
}
name::~name()
{
    std::cout << "distructing..." << std::endl;
}
char* name::show()
{
    char temp[62];
    strcpy_s(temp, first);
    strcat_s(temp, " ");
    strcat_s(temp, mid);
    strcat_s(temp, " ");
    strcat_s(temp, last);
    return temp;
}
int main()
{
    name a("kinan", "fathee", "ayed");
    std::cout << a.show() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `std::string`s ?

Comment: `show` returns a dangling pointer to a local.

Comment: `strncpy_s` takes 4 parameters, you pass 3. `else` are odd.

Comment: It's a uni project and they not allow us to use strings

Comment: @273K ``strncpy_s`` in C++ is also provided as a template in MSVC that deduces the destination buffer size, so that's why 3 parameters works.

Comment: So you're allowed to use <cstring> but not std::string? If you can, you might just as well write it all with loops yourself - you might learn more ;)

Comment: strcpy_s, strcat_s, strncpy_s returns an errno value. It's 0 if it's success, otherwise it returns an error. You can check to see which one fails.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn they all returned 0 :(

Comment: `strcpy_s()` gives undefined behaviour if the length argument is greater than the actual length of the array.   Your `if`/`else` does not guarantee that ALL of `lenF`, `lenM`, and `lenL` are less than or equal to 20 - and the following calls of `strncpy_s()` give undefined behaviour if ANY of them are more than 20.  For example, if `lenF` and `lenM` are both initially more than 20, `lenF`  is set to 20 but `lenF` is not changed - so the following call of `strnpy_s()` that uses `lenF` has undefined behaviour.

Comment: @kinan-not-found *It's a uni project and they not allow us to use strings* -- If the name of the course has `C++` in it, then you are being cheated.  You are learning `C`, not C++.  Also, `std::string` has been part of C++ for officially **24 years** now.  Those idiotic limitations that universities put on C++ students has now gotten to the ridiculous stage.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie actually they didn't even teach us the strings and the course's name is c++ : )

Comment: Are you allowed to create your *own* string class? At least to store the length of those names and not beeing forced to call `strlen` or searching for `'\0'` multiple times (like at *every* call to `strcat`)?

Comment: @kinan-not-found -- So basically the university course blew the dust off an old `C` course outline or an outline of a C++ course from the early 1990's, and giving this to the students.  BTW, to get around this, create your own `string` class, as mentioned.  You would learn a lot more doing that than throwing around `new[]/delete[]` all over the place just to accommodate handling dynamic string data.

Comment: I will do a class then should I make it for only the length?

Comment: BTW, `show` seems the wrong name to me, it doesn't really describe what that function is doing. Are you sure it shouldn't be something like `void name::show() { std::cout << first << ' ' << ...}`?

Comment: @Bob__ actullay that what the uni project tells to do "create a show function that returns char* (the full name)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic for returning the full name is incorrect. You have a local variable `temp` and you are returning a reference to that variable. However, this variable is destroyed once `show()` function is completed. So, in your `main` function you have a reference but its pointing to something that is already destroyed. That's why you will see random characters when you print it. Here is the solution to your problem. You need to create a dynamic array i.e a pointer so that it does not get destroyed.

```
char *name::show()
{
    int size = strlen(first) + strlen(mid) + strlen(last) + 3;
    char *temp = new char[size];
    strcpy_s(temp, size, first);
    strcat_s(temp, size, " ");
    strcat_s(temp, size, mid);
    strcat_s(temp, size, " ");
    strcat_s(temp, size, last);
    return temp;
}

int main()
{
    name a("kinan", "fathee", "ayed");
    char *temp = a.show();
    std::cout << temp << std::endl;
    delete[] temp;
}
```

Edit: In your original code, if you print `temp` at the end of `show` function before returning it, you will see that `temp` contains full name.

Edit: Temp is a local variable. Every local variable is destroyed at the end of the function's execution. In the suggested solution, I am creating an array dynamically on the heap. When we dynamically create an array, it's not removed from the heap automatically. So, when I return a reference to that array and use it in main it still works.

Edit:
I have added `delete[]` in `main` function to deallocate memory.

Comment: No mention of having to call `delete[]` to free the memory?

Comment: but I have a function returns a value then why should destroying temp will cause problems?

Comment: Basically, every local variable is destroyed once function execution is completed and you are returning reference to that destroyed variable

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I thought that deleting the string is out of the scope of the query so I did not mention it. Yes, the allocated memory should be deleted in the main function.

Comment: @Bob__ yes that's a good point.

Answer (score -3):

Should be reserved 1 character for '\0', therefore you need to write `strncpy_s(first, f, lenF - 1);`